How to get LinkedIn user's Title and Supertitle?
I would like to use the LinkedIn API to get the authenticated user's title and super title.
Title: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/titles
Super Title: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/super-titles
Title is mentioned in the Postition Profile fields (here). The page does not describe which permission is required to access these fields. The Profile Field Projections page (here) says "The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for a LinkedIn Partner Program". I cannot find the field to get the Super Title.
I do have the r_basicprofile permission.
I call https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,headline,position and receive the following response:
{
  "status": 403,
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
  "message": "Not enough permission to access field position"
}

I've also tried title, supertitle, and organization field and got similar errors.
Which permission or Partner Program do I need to be able to access the field to get the title and supertitle for the  user?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm answering my own question for posterity and the LinkedIn dev community.

Use the LinkedIn Zendesk to actually get a response from LinkedIn Support https://linkedin.zendesk.com/

LinkedIn support told me this does require the r_fullprofile permission, which is closed. Also, superTitles are not available for Marketing Developer Platform partners at this time.


